# How to represent convolution matrix as a string diagram?

Tags: category-theory, machine-learning, monoidal-categories

I'm trying to represent common machine learning/deep learning concepts and operations in the form of string diagrams. The many categorical quantum mechanics papers by Coecke et al have given me a good start on representing basic linear algebra, but there are a few missing pieces when translating to machine learning.

A very common type of neural network is a convolutional neural network, in which your input is typically a matrix of pixel values (a grayscale image) or possibly a 3-tensor if the image is RGG. Taking the simplest case, you will have at least one small convolutional matrix/kernel that you compute the dot produce of this kernel and a equally sized patch of the input image. By 'sliding' the convolution matrix across the input image 1 pixel at a time and computing the dot product, you build up a new matrix.

In practice, this operation is typically implemented as just a large matrix-matrix multiplication by reshaping the input image; however, this obscures the intuitive idea of a small matrix 'scanning' across the image. Is there anyway I can represent a convolution operation like this in a string diagram notation a la Coecke and others? I also want to know how to represent entry-wise matrix multiplication in string diagrams (matrix-matrix multiplication is easy, it's just two boxes sequentially composed along a string).

Comment: Is discrete convolution of matrices even basis independent?

Comment: @bianchira: I'm 90% confident that "matrix" is not being used to refer to a member of a matrix algebra, but instead something that is merely a multi-dimensional array of numbers. My brief impression is that this usage seems to be somewhat of a norm in ML settings.

Comment: ... although in this particular case there is added structure to the array of numbers, in that the indices into the array (and, in particular, the numerical differences of the indices) are actually meaningful.

Comment: ... and I suspect the usage of the word "matrix" here is misleading the OP into trying to shoehorn his setting into someplace where it doesn't, since it's not really being used in a way resembling an element of a matrix algebra.

Comment: @Hurkyl yes matrix as in 2d array of numbers. Not as an operator. But we could also consider a 2d array flattened into a vector and I want to convolve over the vector.

Comment: Let $V, W$ be modules over some ring $k$, a choice of basis on each gives an isomorphism of sets $Hom_{Set}(Z_{dim V} \times Z_{dim W}, k) \simeq Hom_{kMod}(V, W)$. Given an operation on the LHS, it's natural to ask whether its image on the RHS is dependent on the choice of isomorphism. In the case that it is, e.g. like a matrix multiplication, then you have a linear operation on the RHS and you're then free to use usual string diagrams for the monoidal category of modules. My previous comment was pointing out that this won't work for a convolution as it depends on the choice of isomorphism.